# How to fix this unchecked assignment warning?

Tags: java, reflection, gson

```
var blks = ReflectionHelper.getClasses("PACKAGE_NAME");
var blockRta = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Block.class);
for (var c : blks) {
    if (Block.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
        blockRta.registerSubtype(c);
    }
}
```

I got `Warning:(31, 46) Unchecked assignment: 'java.lang.Class' to 'java.lang.Class<? extends PACKAGE_NAME.Block>'` warning on the line `blockRta.registerSubtype(c);`, but I can't figure out how to fix that without supressing it.

`ReflectionHelper.getClasses` is a static method to get all the classes in that package name, and its return type is `Class[]`. `Block` is an interface. `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` is a class in gson extra, and its source code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java).

Comment: Does the error message really say `? extends PACKAGE_NAME` and not `? extends Block`? Assuming the latter, give `c` an explicit type, `for(Class<?> c: blks)`, then use `blockRta.registerSubtype(c.asSubclass(Block.class));`

Comment: @Holger Yes, you are right. But using `asSubclass` still won't work, it just produce `Unchecked assignment: 'java.lang.Class' to 'java.lang.Class? extends PACKAGE_NAME.Block>'. Reason: 'c' has raw type, so result of asSubclass is erased` instead.

Comment: That’s why I said that you must change the declaration of `c`. To cite myself, “give `c` an explicit type, `for(Class<?> c: blks)`, *then* …”

Comment: @Holger Thanks, that works for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ReflectionHelper.getClasses` returns an array of the raw type `Class`, the local-variable type inference will use this raw type `Class[]` for `var blks` and in turn, the raw type `Class` for `var c`. Using the raw type `Class` for `c` allows passing it to `registerSubtype(Class<? extends Block>)`, without any check, but not without any warning. You can use the method `asSubclass` to perform a *checked* conversion, but you have to declare an explicit non-raw variable type, to get rid of the raw type, as otherwise, even the result of the `asSubclass` invocation will be erased to a raw type by the compiler.

There are two approaches. Change the type of `blks`:

```
Class<?>[] blks = ReflectionHelper.getClasses("PACKAGE_NAME");
var blockRta = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Block.class);
for(var c: blks) {
    if (Block.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
        blockRta.registerSubtype(c.asSubclass(Block.class));
    }
}
```

Then, the type of `var c` changes automatically to `Class<?>`.

Or just change the type of `c`:

```
var blks = ReflectionHelper.getClasses("PACKAGE_NAME");
var blockRta = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Block.class);
for(Class<?> c: blks) {
    if (Block.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
        blockRta.registerSubtype(c.asSubclass(Block.class));
    }
}
```